# datediff for records in a single resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having one scenario where i need to compare the dates in a single resultset.
For example if i am having a table with 5 rows having different dates.

```
Table1
ID DATE
1  2014/01/01
2  2014/02/01
3  2014/03/01
4  2014/04/01
5  2014/05/02
```

In the above table, i need to return true or false depending upon the date difference.So, if any of two dates having date difference of 30 then it will return true.

I want to do it in SQL.

I have tried with

```
 SELECT 
         case when count(*)>0 then 1 else 0 end
    FROM 
         Table AS T1 CROSS JOIN Table AS T2    
    WHERE 
         DATEDIFF(DD,T1.VISIT_DATE,T2.VISIT_DATE)<=30
```

But above query is not working as expected.
 I need some suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: which version of sqlserver are you using ?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008.Thanks.

Comment: Excepted output : if one row compare with other rows in the same table and date difference is less than 30 then it will return true.Like the row will compare with rest rows not with itself.

Comment: That isn't a complete description of an expected output.   What does "return true" mean?   What columns will be in your desired results?   what rows?

Comment: For example , {Entity ID:1,Date:2014/01/01},{Entity ID:1,Date:2014/01/02},{Entity ID:1,Date:2014/01/03},{Entity ID:1,Date:2014/01/04}.Here above are four records, likewise i might have many no of rows  with different entity ids.I need to calculate the entity ids having date checks.DateCheck condition is , if each date compare with rest of the dates of same entity id and if atleast one date difference is 30 days, then that entity ids are needed as final output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a (correlated) sub-query:

```
SELECT LessThan30days = CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS
                        (
                          SELECT 1 FROM Table AS T2
                          WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,T1.VISIT_DATE,T2.VISIT_DATE) <= 30)  
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM Table AS T1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2012 or later I think this is what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @example TABLE (ID int, DT datetime)
INSERT INTO @example(ID, DT)
SELECT 1,'2014/01/01'
UNION SELECT 2,'2014/02/01'
UNION SELECT 3,'2014/03/01'
UNION SELECT 4,'2014/04/01'
UNION SELECT 5,'2014/05/02'

;with rowsWithDayDifference as (
  SELECT ID, DT, DATEDIFF(day,LAG(DT) OVER (ORDER BY DT),DT) as DayDifference
  FROM @example
) 
select *, CASE WHEN DayDifference<=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Is30DaysOrLess
from rowsWithDayDifference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- sample data start

declare @t table (id int, d datetime)
insert into @t values (1, '2014/01/01')
insert into @t values (2, '2014/02/01')
insert into @t values (3, '2014/03/01')
insert into @t values (4, '2014/04/01')
insert into @t values (5, '2014/05/02')

-- sample data end

select t1.*, t2.d as d2, datediff(day, t2.d, t1.d)
    from @t t1 left outer join @t t2 on (t1.id-1) = t2.id
```